# Specified cast not valid?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

**SOLVED**

**The issue was that I changed my SQL server tables, but then didn't change the my Entity in my C#. Thanks for all of the ideas back!**

*** D Stanley Thanks for making me check my Errors.

```
public partial class xamlAuditorDashboard : Window
{
    cEvolve_SP sp = new cEvolve_SP(Properties.Settings.Default.AppConnectionString);
    List<cAuditTasksEntity> _tasks;
    cAuditUserEntity _loggedInUser;
    public xamlAuditorDashboard(cAuditUserEntity loggedInUser)
    {
        _loggedInUser = loggedInUser;
        InitializeComponent();
        _tasks = new List<cAuditTasksEntity>();
        Refresh();
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {

        var _AuditUserId = _loggedInUser;
        cAuditUserEntity user = _AuditUserId as cAuditUserEntity;

        int userid = user.AuditUserId;

        _tasks = sp.GetTasksByUser(userid).ToList();
        cmbList.ItemsSource = (from cAuditTasksEntity tasks in _tasks
                                    select tasks.TaskId).ToList();

    }
}
```

I am finding the Logged on user by passing the logged on user to the constructor, and then setting it as `_loggedInUser = loggedInUser;`

For that user, I am finding out there ID in the `Refresh` method, and eventually get their ID and set it as `userid`.

I run my SP (Stored Procedure) which selects all under a specified ID 
`_tasks = sp.GetTasksByUser(userid).ToList();`

It is suppose to bring back all the column results they have in that table, under that ID and put it into the combobox `cmbList.ItemsSource = (from cAuditTasksEntity tasks in _tasks
                                        select tasks.TaskId).ToList();`

But the line of running the Store Procedure it is saying that it is an invalid cast?

EDIT:

This is the code in my class for the Stored Procedure:

```
        [Function(Name = "SP_AUDIT_TASKS_GET_TASKS_BY_USER", IsComposable = false)]
    public ISingleResult<cAuditTasksEntity> GetTasksByUser(
       [Parameter(Name = "pAuditUserId", DbType = "INT")] int AuditUserId)
    {
        IExecuteResult objResult = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()), AuditUserId);

        ISingleResult<cAuditTasksEntity> objresults = (ISingleResult<cAuditTasksEntity>)objResult.ReturnValue;

        return objresults;
    }
```

This is the SQL code :

```
        SELECT *
    FROM Audit_Tasks    
        WHERE (AuditUserId = @pAuditUserId)
```

Comment: Still waiting for the `sql` and `sql-server` part of your code... What parameter type does the stored procedure expect?

Comment: are you sure cAuditTasksEntity returns a list of the same type as ItemsSource ?

Comment: What type does `GetTasksByUser` return?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Sorry, I have added the code I think this is what you meant?

Comment: @Maess Where would I find this out?

Comment: @DStanley Added the code in my question.

Comment: I would also check the types of `cAuditTasksEntity` properties against the fields of `Audit_Tasks` to make sure they are mapped properly (by name and type).  `SELECT *` can cause issues like this when columns are addded/removed/modified.

Comment: @DStanley Do you mean in my select statment in my SP to specify the columns?

Comment: Possibly - right now you just need to validate that the columns map to the properties correctly - that's where the invalid cast could be happening.

Comment: @DStanley I just checked and I remember changing the SQL table but didn't change in class. I changed and it still comes out with the Cast Error on line `_tasks = sp.GetTasksByUser(userid).ToList();`